# Can a voltaic pile be used as a capacitor?

Tags: batteries, capacitor

The electrolyte of a voltaic pile can be thought of as the dielectric of a capacitor. The cathode and anode of the pile are the plates of a parallel-plate capacitor. So can a voltaic pile be used as if it were capacitors connected in series?

Comment: An electrolyte is a conductor, so by definition, it is not a dielectric in the sense that you need here.

Comment: can you give me example ? where you wanna use it ?

Comment: @DaveTweed Shoot, didn't notice that.

Comment: @arashzgh I was thinking of using a zinc, copper, brine voltaic pile as a capacitor

Comment: actually voltaic pile not exactly like capacitor . voltaic pile generate voltage and active component but capacitor just save energy and passive component .

Comment: Aren't super-capacitors electrolytic/voltaic devices? It's just terminology, they are not capable of negative cycle. To use voltaic devices as capacitors, you'd have to bias the circuit to a little above peak signal amplitude. For example for a signal +/-5V peak-peak, you'd need to bias the circuit to ~5.5V and a voltaic device capable of handling 11V.

Answer (score 1):

A capacitor and battery are just models that we use to describe physical processes. Capacitors are defined as the effect of the electric field between two plates of metal, and there doesn't have to be a dielectric. The dielectric modifies the electric field between plates.
The dielectric is from a dipole moment of the electric field and is dependent on the material

$$ E_{effective} = \frac{\sigma}{k\epsilon_0}$$

This changes the capacitance $$ C = \frac{k\epsilon_0A}{d} $$ by a factor of k (the k factor being related to the dielectric effect of the material)

Batteries have some internal capacitance, because they have plates of metal in them, but they also generate a voltage because of the ionic processes. One way to simply model a battery would be this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3wV3Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In a battery the ionic processes are going to dominate the charging of any 'capacitance' of the cell (the voltage source is connected directly to the 'capacitor' created by the cell plates).
You can stack cells together but you aren't going to be able to measure or see many effects from this capacitance. There are more complex models of batteries, but this is a way to illustrate what would happen. It really isn't going to affect anything in the DC sense, and it would be silly to run an AC current through the battery.

Comment: IIRC, AC measurements are used to measure the battery's internal impedance.